# Mongoose cannot findOne({_id : id}) with copied documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I copied documents from a local database to my production database and when I try to get the document by Id by running model.findOne({_id : id}) and mongoose returns nothing. I am copying the documents over with the same Id, but I also tried with a new Id. I can find the document in the database and confirm that the JSON is correct, the Id is correct, etc and it won't find it. The documents I did not copy and where generated via my app still query fine with the findOne command. So, I have no idea what's going on

any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

groups.crud

```
getGroupById(id: string) {
    logger.debug(".getGroupById id: " + id);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        GroupsModel.findById(id)
        .populate('createdBy')
        .then(function (group) {
            logger.debug(".getGroupById");
            if(group.createdBy.privacySettings.useUserName) {
                group.createdBy.firstName = '';
                group.createdBy.lastName = '';
            }
            resolve(group);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            reject(error);
        });

    });

}
```

groups.routes

```
getGroupById(req, res, next) {
        logger.debug('.getGroupById: BEG');
        let id = req.params.id;
        return groupsCrud.getGroupById(id)
        .then(function(group) {
            if(group) {
                logger.debug('.getGroupById: get by id success');
                let response = {
                    data : group
                }
                logger.debug('.getGroupById: response: ' + response);
                res.json(response);
            }
            else {
                logger.debug('.getGroupById: get by id failed 1');
                res.status(404).json({ status : 404, message : "Group not found."});
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            logger.debug('.getGroupById: get by id failed 2 err = ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
            res.sendStatus(404);
        });


    }
```

Comment: did you try Model.findById(id) ? it would be easy for us if you provide the sample code and check id you are passing is of type ObjectId(id) not a string. If it is a string, better to use findById.

Comment: I am passing back a string. ex: "5b8833a482f4b171446ca931" I am trying the findById. waiting for it to deploy

Comment: Ok Let me know if it works.

Comment: it did not work. I will post the code

Comment: Yes. Please complete the question so that we can re-generate/go over the issue.

Comment: I posted the code in an edit. The part that is dumbfounding me is that it finds documents that were created fine. Just can't find any documents I copied over.. I'm assuming this as something to do with how mongo sets the _id and how an ObjectId has a timestamp in it